# Best way to evaluate string conditions like "User.Name.Length>0" as true or false?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

What is the best way to evaluate at runtime conditional expressions which are stored as strings.

I am using MVC3, .NET4, C#4.

So assume the solution was a method called "Eval" then:

```
if eval("User.Name.Length>0")
{return true;}
```

should behave in the same way as:

```
if (User.Name.Length>0)
{return true;}
```

So I need to also access any inscope .NET types as part of this solution.

So what would be a solution for "Eval"?

Thanks.

P.S I had posted a seperate question on this focusing on Dynamic LINQ as the solution. However I now think my solution is more simple, hence this question.

EDIT. Do not read too much into the "User". It could be any object. I am interested in how to evaluate string expressions at runtime as if they had been written explicitely at compile time. Another example might be:

```
if eval("mycat.coatcolour=='ginger'")
{return true;}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? If you really need to do it this way, you can use reflection.

Comment: So to hear that you are lost David :) Basically I am storing these strings as rules in a DB hence why they are string and data.

Comment: And why are you storing them as strings?

Comment: Is this in the webpage or the backend?

Comment: For complex systems - own DSL using IronPython and DynamicCLR as a case

Comment: They are stored in the DB as strings, because that is the only way to store rules as data. They are then pulled back as data and then used in the MVC View(via Razor) to determine whether certain data is displayed.

Comment: @EdB: Someone made a serious design flaw. Even if you could eval, how do you bind `User` to an instance of it?

Comment: >because that is the only way to store rules as data.
But that is wrong. There are many different ways to save expressions as data.

Comment: One option is to use an [ExpressionSerializer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ExpressionSerializer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4000) and store the Expressions in an XML format in the DB, instead of strings representing some code.

Comment: Basically I have a complex document object which I interrogate for the existence of this before I display certain data items. I have looked at Dynamic LINQ, TryParse, NCalc. I thought TryParse was a simple answe,but this only converts "True" to true.

Comment: OK, Thanks for pointing out that storing rules as only strings is wrong. Just an assumption on my part. Taking one step back, how should I achieve this bearing in mind that I want to persist simple rules in the DB. Come to think of it there is something s can BRE I think that persists rules as XML then uses LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to implement own parser and use reflection / FastMember to navigate the path or look for a scripting solution like [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/).

Comment: Even with CS-Script, you still have the problem binding `User` to the instance.

Comment: @leppie - yes, there will be some modification required in order to get the current 'context' / root object.

Comment: Folks, Do not read too much into "User". It could be any Class. I am interested in how to evaluate a string expression at runtime. So it could be "myCat.CoatColour=="Ginger".

Comment: @EdB: That is exactly what we are discussing :) Somehow you will need to bind instances to variable names and also clean them up later on.

Comment: This question is still open if anybody else has thought. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the benefit of all, I am sharing this very useful blog: http://gautam-m.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-net.html. I am going to try using FLEE since it can access object properties and is mature.